# Displaying image from custom object in Chatter Feed thru Apex

Tags: apex, chatter, feeditem

I have a custom object (badge) , it has a imageUrl field which is the public url for the image. I have a formula field called Thumbnail which uses IMAGE function to use the imageUrl to display the image in the detail page for the object.

How can i use either the imageUrl or Thumbnail to post a chatter feed using the FeedItem object usng Apex ?

```
sObject fItem = (sObject)System.Type.forName('FeedItem').newInstance();
   fitem.put('ParentId' ,UserInfo.getUserId()); 
    fItem.put('Body' , UserInfo.getName()+' won a badge. <apex:image url="'+badge.Image_Url__c+'" />' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt find any direct way to embed image into a post but ended up posting the image as attachment, got the answer from this post:
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hahYAAQ